# What are those implicit "rules" by which we deduce theorems from axioms in mathematics?

Tags: proof-writing, natural-deduction

In purely formal mathematics - meaning using inference rules to derive new theorems from axioms (like in Hilbert calculus) - there is explicitly told how to deduce new theorems. However in most of mathematics, we use not very obvious implicit "rules" for deducing new theorems (meaning like in informal proofs). Would you be able to somehow explicitly tell what "rules" we use in those types of deductions (I guess it is some kind of semantic meaning of the words by which we reason)? If there are no explicit rules for deducing new theorems in this type of deduction, how do we know that the theorem really follows from those axioms?

Comment: If you have any reason to downvote my question, please tell me the reason so that I could correct my question. Thanks.

Comment: Questions like this begin to enter the realm of philosophy. I could also ask about many implicit assumptions you probably make, such as are the letters/words you typed the same that I see (and they will also be the same if I look away for a few moments and then look back), if you write a "theta" symbol on paper and then type $\theta$ in what way are these implicitly assumed to be the same if someone is reading a handwritten vs. typed version of a mathematical proof you've written, does it matter whether the rules are described by talking or must they be written, etc. (BTW, I didn't downvote.)

Comment: [Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/) has been formalized by [Gentzen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Gentzen) exactly in order to fit with the "usual" mathematical practice. Some are more "natural": Conditional Proof, Proof by Contradiction, Proof by Cases, Simplification, Addition, Universal Instantiation and Generalization, Existential Introducion; some less (e.g. Existential Elimination.